# Compiling Angular app: Error: export 'ɵwithHttpTransferCache' (imported as 'ɵwithHttpTransferCache') was not found in '@angular/common/http'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient, angular-http, angular17

I've recently updated [my app](https://github.com/azerothcore/Keira3) to Angular 17 and I'm getting this weird error at compile time:

> ./node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm2022/platform-browser.mjs:2016:81-103
>
> - Error: export 'ɵwithHttpTransferCache' (imported as 'ɵwithHttpTransferCache') was not found in '@angular/common/http'
>   (possible exports: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpBackend, HttpClient,
>   HttpClientJsonpModule, HttpClientModule, HttpClientXsrfModule,
>   HttpContext, HttpContextToken, HttpErrorResponse, HttpEventType,
>   HttpHandler, HttpHeaderResponse, HttpHeaders, HttpParams, HttpRequest,
>   HttpResponse, HttpResponseBase, HttpUrlEncodingCodec, HttpXhrBackend,
>   HttpXsrfTokenExtractor, JsonpClientBackend, JsonpInterceptor,
>   XhrFactory, ɵHttpInterceptingHandler,
>   ɵangular_packages_common_http_http_a,
>   ɵangular_packages_common_http_http_b,
>   ɵangular_packages_common_http_http_c,
>   ɵangular_packages_common_http_http_d,
>   ɵangular_packages_common_http_http_e,
>   ɵangular_packages_common_http_http_f,
>   ɵangular_packages_common_http_http_g)
>
> ./node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm2022/platform-browser.mjs:2101:252-274
>
> - Error: export 'ɵwithHttpTransferCache' (imported as 'ɵwithHttpTransferCache') was not found in '@angular/common/http'
>   (possible exports: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpBackend, HttpClient,
>   HttpClientJsonpModule, HttpClientModule, HttpClientXsrfModule,
>   HttpContext, HttpContextToken, HttpErrorResponse, HttpEventType,
>   HttpHandler, HttpHeaderResponse, HttpHeaders, HttpParams, HttpRequest,
>   HttpResponse, HttpResponseBase, HttpUrlEncodingCodec, HttpXhrBackend,
>   HttpXsrfTokenExtractor, JsonpClientBackend, JsonpInterceptor,
>   XhrFactory, ɵHttpInterceptingHandler,
>   ɵangular_packages_common_http_http_a,
>   ɵangular_packages_common_http_http_b,
>   ɵangular_packages_common_http_http_c,
>   ɵangular_packages_common_http_http_d,
>   ɵangular_packages_common_http_http_e,
>   ɵangular_packages_common_http_http_f,
>   ɵangular_packages_common_http_http_g)

Answer (score 1):

It took me several attempts but eventually, I solved it by simply deleting the Angular cache folder (by default it is located at `.angular`) and rebuilding my app.

```
rm -rf .angular
```

Alternatively:

```
ng cache clean
```

More info about Angular cache:

https://angular.io/cli/cache